# Launch Bootstrap Modal on Page Load, Contingent on Previous Page Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is related to several questions re. invoking a Bootstrap modal, but it has a special circumstance, viz:

Page A has a button, which when clicked, loads Page B, AND invokes a modal on Page B.

Modal on Page B opens by two methods; from Page A button click, OR, Page B button click.

If a user navigates to Page B by any means OTHER THAN Page A button click, Page B modal remains hidden until Page B button click.

Is this clear?

Page B button click currently functions to open modal. Need to open Page B modal on Page A button click.

Suggested solutions appreciated.

mjb

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a querystring parameter to Page B.

**Page A**

`<a href="pageB?openModal=true">Go to Page B</a>`

**Page B**

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('openModal') != -1) {
  $("#modal").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: sorry. tried to format a followup, failed, and deleted.

I should mention this is in context of a WP site, using stock Bootstrap modal methodology.

So, not sure how to implement using your above suggestion.

Comment: You can put the js in a script tag in Page B or in an external file that's included in Page B.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a window location service to trigger a standard bootstrap modal independently from any link (internal or external), you can do it like this:

Standard Bootstrap Modal setup:

`<div class="modal fade" id="dynaModal">Content</div>`

Inside jQuery on ready or on load (be sure the page has loaded or get error):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $(hash).modal('toggle');
}
```

1. First line checks to see if the url contains a hash
2. Second line sets the hash variable to the hash found in the url
3. Third line toggles a modal whose id matches the found hash

Example Link for #dynaModal:

```
<a href="pageB.html#dynaModal">Open Page B Modal</a>
```

If the hash doesn't match a modal's ID, the code doesn't run. If the code finds a hash in the url that matches a modal's ID, the code runs.